# Highlights subString in the TableCell(s) which is using for JTable filetering

Tags: java, swing, jtable, highlighting, rowfilter

how is possible to synchonize text typed into `JTextField` (then by `DocumentListener` passed `String` to the `RowFilter`) with `TableCell` if contains same as String value in JTextField/Document,

and then highlights (meaning f.e. change text `Color.Red`) for identical text in synchronized `TableCell(s)`

I know that by usage of some hacks is that possible by using

1/ by using `getTableCellRendererComponent`

2/ by using `prepareRenderer`

is there another and maybe correct way(s)

little bit modified code from JTable tutorial

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableFilterSorter extends JPanel {

    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TableFilterSorter() {
        super(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        final JTextField filterCpText = new JTextField();
        filterCpText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
        filterCpText.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        filterCpText.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        JPanel filterCpPanel = new JPanel();
        filterCpPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        filterCpPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        filterCpPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        filterCpPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));
        filterCpPanel.add(filterCpText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(filterCpPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        final JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 160));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        TableModel myTableModel = table.getModel();
        final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(myTableModel);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        filterCpText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            private void searchFieldChangedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                String text = filterCpText.getText();
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                    table.clearSelection();
                } else {
                    try {
                        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text, 4));
                        table.clearSelection();
                    } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad regex pattern",
                                "Bad regex pattern", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searchFieldChangedUpdate(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
            {"Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), false},
            {"Alison", "Huml", "Rowing", new Integer(3), true},
            {"Kathy", "Walrath", "Knitting", new Integer(2), false},
            {"Sharon", "Zakhour", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), true},
            {"Philip", "Milne", "Pool", new Integer(10), false},
            {"Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), false},
            {"Alison", "Huml", "Rowing", new Integer(3), true},
            {"Kathy", "Walrath", "Knitting", new Integer(2), false},
            {"Sharon", "Zakhour", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), true},
            {"Philip", "Milne", "Pool", new Integer(10), false},};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                        + " to " + value + " (an instance of " + value.getClass() + ")");
            }
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableFilterSorter newContentPane = new TableFilterSorter();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JXTable can do so via a Highlighter - see swinglabs-demos for an example (MatchingTextHighlighter in the search demo) - there a background highlight is applied by a Painter.

You can do something like that manually somewhere in your renderer. If using a JLabel as renderingComponent, you basically have to find parts of the text that need the background highlight and paint the background for that region (below is a code snippet for finding the areas, c&p from the demos example). Alternatively you might consider using a JTextField as rendering component: the adv is that Highlighter (from javax.swing.text) is built-in, the disadv are the usual issues with text comps as renderers ;-)

```
/**
 * Finds the rectangles that contain rendered characters that match the
 * pattern.
 * 
 * @param object an optional configuration parameter. This may be null.
 * @param width width of the area to paint.
 * @param height height of the area to paint.
 * @return a <code>List</code> of <code>Rectangle</code>s marking characters
 *         to highlight
 */
protected List<Rectangle> findHighlightAreas(JLabel object, int width,
        int height) {
    String text = object.getText();

    insets = object.getInsets(insets);

    viewR.x = 0 + insets.left;
    viewR.y = 0 + insets.bottom;
    viewR.width = width - insets.right;
    viewR.height = height - insets.top;

    // Reset the text and view rectangle x any y coordinates.
    // These are not set to 0 in SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel
    iconR.x = iconR.y = 0;
    textR.x = textR.y = 0;

    FontMetrics fm = object.getFontMetrics(object.getFont());
    String clippedText = SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(object, fm,
            text, object.getIcon(), object.getVerticalAlignment(), object
                    .getHorizontalAlignment(), object
                    .getVerticalTextPosition(), object
                    .getHorizontalTextPosition(), viewR, iconR, textR,
            object.getIconTextGap());

    int xOffset = calculateXOffset(object, viewR, textR);

    String textToSearch = clippedText;
    // Check to see if the text will be clipped
    if (!object.getText().equals(clippedText)) {
        // TODO There has to be a better way that assuming ellipses
        // are the last characters of the text
        textToSearch = clippedText.substring(0, clippedText.length() - 3);
    }

    return createHighlightAreas(textToSearch, fm, xOffset, height);
}

/**
 * Creates the rectangles that contain matched characters in the given text.
 * 
 * @param text the text to search
 * @param fm the font metrics of the rendered font
 * @param xOffset the x offset at which text rendering starts
 * @param height the height of painted highlights
 * @return a <code>List</code> of highlight areas to paint
 */
protected List<Rectangle> createHighlightAreas(String text, FontMetrics fm,
        int xOffset, int height) {
    SearchPredicate predicate = (SearchPredicate) getHighlightPredicate();
    Matcher matcher = predicate.getPattern().matcher(text);

    List<Rectangle> highlightAreas = null;
    int startFrom = 0;
    while (startFrom < text.length() && matcher.find(startFrom)) {
        if (highlightAreas == null) {
            highlightAreas = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        }

        int start = matcher.start();
        int end = matcher.end();

        if (start == end) {
            // empty matcher will cause infinite loop
            break;
        }

        startFrom = end;

        int highlightx;
        int highlightWidth;

        if (start == 0) {
            // start highlight from the start of the field
            highlightx = textR.x + xOffset;
        } else {
            // Calculate the width of the unhighlighted text to
            // get the start of the highlighted region.
            String strToStart = text.substring(0, start);
            highlightx = textR.x + fm.stringWidth(strToStart) + xOffset;
        }

        // Get the width of the highlighted region
        String highlightText = text.substring(start, end);
        highlightWidth = fm.stringWidth(highlightText);

        highlightAreas.add(new Rectangle(highlightx, 0, highlightWidth,
                height));
    }

    if (highlightAreas == null) {
        highlightAreas = Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        coalesceHighlightAreas(highlightAreas);
    }
    return highlightAreas;
}

/**
 * Joins highlight rectangles that mark adjacent horizontal areas into
 * single rectangles. This is useful to renderers that vary horizontally,
 * such a horizontal gradient - the gradient will not restart when there are
 * two adjacent highlight areas.
 * 
 * @param highlightAreas a <code>List</code> of <code>Rectangle</code>s.
 */
protected void coalesceHighlightAreas(List<Rectangle> highlightAreas) {
    Collections.sort(highlightAreas, X_AXIS_RECTANGLE_COMPARATOR);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < highlightAreas.size() - 1) {
        Rectangle r1 = highlightAreas.get(i);
        Rectangle r2 = highlightAreas.get(i + 1);

        if (r1.x + r1.width == r2.x) {
            r1.width += r2.width;
            highlightAreas.remove(i + 1);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Calculates the x offset of highlights based on component orientation and
 * text direction.
 * 
 * @param component the renderer component
 * @param viewR the view rectangle of the renderer component
 * @param textR the text rectangle of the renderer component
 * @return the number of pixels to offset the highlight from the left edge
 *         of the component
 */
protected int calculateXOffset(JLabel component, Rectangle viewR,
        Rectangle textR) {
    int horizAlignment = component.getHorizontalAlignment();
    boolean leftToRight = component.getComponentOrientation()
            .isLeftToRight();

    if (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.LEFT
            || (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.LEADING && leftToRight)
            || (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.TRAILING && !leftToRight)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.RIGHT
            || (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.TRAILING && !leftToRight)
            || (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.LEADING && leftToRight)) {
        return viewR.width - textR.width;
    } else if (horizAlignment == SwingConstants.CENTER) {
        return (viewR.width - textR.width) / 2;
    }
    throw new AssertionError("Unknown horizonal alignment "
            + horizAlignment);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

inspired by kleopatra' reply, I tried everything what's possible or know, now result is that her example invoking me `Pattern`

[image]

looks like Pattern is quickiest, more than I expected, this code missed something about RowSorter, it going about idea how to doing it, with quick output to the GUI,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class HiglightNumberValueInTableCell {

    private String testS;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("frameTitle");
    private JScrollPane tblS = new JScrollPane();
    private JTable tbl;
    private Vector<String> rOrH;
    private long t1 = 0L;
    private long t2 = 0L;

    public HiglightNumberValueInTableCell() {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int regLenght = 25000;
        int chars = 0;
        AlphaChars aChars = new AlphaChars();
        testS = aChars.getNext(regLenght);
        rOrH = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Vector<String>> rowD = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (int e = 0; e < regLenght;) {
            chars++;
            //if (chars > 50) { //one char in table cell
            if (chars > 20) {
                chars = 1;
                rowD.add(rOrH);
                rOrH = new Vector<String>();
            }
            //String str = (testS.substring(e, (e + 1))).toString();//one char in table cell
            String str = (testS.substring(e, (e + 5))).toString();
            if (str != null) {
                rOrH.add(str);
            } else {
                rOrH.add("");
            }
            //e++;//one char in table cell
            e += 5;
        }
        rOrH = new Vector<String>();
        //for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {//one char in table cell
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            rOrH.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        }
        tbl = new JTable(rowD, rOrH);
        tblS = new JScrollPane(tbl, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        tblS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 403));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tblS, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.pack();
        addColumnRenderes();
    }

    private void addColumnRenderes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            RowColorRenderer rowRenderer = new RowColorRenderer(i);
            TableColumn column = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer(rowRenderer);
        }
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                showFrame();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private void showFrame() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
                t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("miliSec:" + (t2 - t1)); //aver. 45 miliSec.
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private class RowColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int colNo = 0;

        RowColorRenderer(int col) {
            colNo = col;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;
            if (!isSelected) {
                if (table.getValueAt(row, colNo) != null) {
                    String str = table.getValueAt(row, colNo).toString();
                    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                        if (Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(str).find()) {
                            if (((Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && (!(Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.magenta);
                                setBackground(Color.orange);
                            } else if ((!(Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && ((Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.blue);
                                setBackground(Color.yellow);
                            } else if (((Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && ((Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.red);
                                setBackground(Color.cyan);
                            }
                            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
                            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                        } else {
                            setBackground(table.getBackground());
                            setForeground(table.getForeground());
                            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 8));
                            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    private class AlphaChars {

        public static final int MIN_LENGTH = 2000;
        private java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        private char[] AlphaChars = {
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
            'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q',
            'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '+', '-', '*', '/', '<', '>', '&',
            '#', '@', '{', '}', '?', ':', '_', '"', '!', ')', '('};

        public String getNext() {
            StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < MIN_LENGTH; i++) {
                strbuf.append(getAlphaChars()[getRand().nextInt(getAlphaChars().length)]);
            }
            return strbuf.toString();
        }

        public String getNext(int reqLenght) {
            StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < reqLenght; i++) {
                strbuf.append(getAlphaChars()[getRand().nextInt(getAlphaChars().length)]);
            }
            return strbuf.toString();
        }

        public java.util.Random getRand() {
            return rand;
        }

        public void setRand(java.util.Random aRand) {
            rand = aRand;
        }

        public char[] getAlphaChars() {
            return AlphaChars;
        }

        public void setAlphaChars(char[] aAlphaChars) {
            AlphaChars = aAlphaChars;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HiglightNumberValueInTableCell hnvit = new HiglightNumberValueInTableCell();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This example highlights the speed benefit of `JTable` renderers, which use the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).