# When is legal call getMagicCaretPosition()

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtextpane, caret

I'm developing an autocompletion functionality (that consists in a little window under the caret position that suggest what you'll writing) extending a `JTextPane`, and in a `KeyAdapter` associated to this component I wrote this:

```
...
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(e.getKeyChar())) {
        p = getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition();
        if (p != null) {
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, this);
            p.x = p.x + 2;
            p.y = p.y + 20;
            autocompletion.setLocation(p.x, p.y);
        }
    }
}
...
```

The problem is that sometime `getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition()` returns null, and I can't understand why.

What is the legal way to invoke this method, or to implement this functionality?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but have you taken a look at [the swing tutorial example about auto-completion in a text area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). It might contain some useful hints

Comment: I already looked, it doesn't help me because in sun's tutorial the autocompletion feature is realized in a complete different way (without another frame).

Comment: Sun's tutorial uses SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). That might also help here as it should help ensure that the Document has been completely updated before you do your processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I hope that (little window ) == `JWindow` don't forget declare [JWindow(Window owner)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html)

2) then you can two choices use

- `JTable` with one Column, there so simple to implements [RowFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), no required solving anything that you describe, only implemented filtering from simple `JTextField`
- `JList` with [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm)

3) `KeyListener` isn't correct listener look at `Document/DocumentListener`

4) easiest and most confortable way is implement a `JTable`, and with [hightlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410839/highlights-substring-in-the-tablecells-which-is-using-for-jtable-filetering)

Comment: Thanks for 2,3,4. About 1, actually I'm using an undecorated and unfocusable `JFrame`, you think isn't a good choice?

Comment: not that wrong idea, put there undecorated JDialog with parent and then toFront works in all cases, btw there are lot of issue manage two JFrames, starting with Focus, toFront ....