# Validating and highlighting JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am highlighting `JTable` cells based on validation. In some conditions, I have to take the value of other columns. For example,  if `column2` has USA then `column3` should be only numeric. As another example, if `col2` is "USA" *and* `col4` is numeric, then `col5` should be only three chars. Can someone suggest how this can be done?

In the fragment below, `col3` contains country names;  `col4` and `col5` depend on `col3`. When I am in `case 3` and in `case 4`, I cannot check the value of `case 2`.  For example, I want like, `if (col3.value == "USA")`.

```
    [code]
    tcol = editorTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

    tcol = editorTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

    tcol = editorTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

    public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object
        value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col){

        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
        isSelected,hasFocus, row, col);

       if (value instanceof String) {
           String str = (String) value;

           switch (col) {
                case 0:
                    col1(str, cell);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    col2(str, cell);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    col3(str, cell);
                    break; 
           }
        }
        return cell;
     }

      private void col1(String str, Component cell) {       
            if(!str.matches("[0-9a-zA-z]")){
                cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
           }
     }

      private void col2(String str, Component cell) {       
         if(!str.matches("[A-Z]{3}")){
             cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
         } else {
              cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
         }
     }
    [/code]
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? simply express your deescription in code ... BTW: beware that the row/column coordinates area _view_ - before basing any model-related logic on them, you'll have to convert them

Comment: 1) use `prepareRenderer` 2) remove `switch (col) {` 3) [simplify code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132400/jtable-row-hightlighter-based-on-value-from-tablecell) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410839/highlights-substring-in-the-tablecells-which-is-using-for-jtable-filetering)

Comment: kleopatra, i have edited my question

Comment: mKorbel, if i am not wrong, prepareRenderer needs looping of all the rows right?  Is it not possible with the current renderer.  I just should be able to get the values of other columns.  Thanks

Comment: 1) use prepareRenderer 2) remove switch (col) { 3) switch of ColumnReordering for ColumnRenderer, 4) your Renderer must be called after any changes in the model or view, 5) have to check convertXxxIndexToXxx()

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kleopatra and @mKorbel are correct. Your fragment is incomplete, but it *appears* as if you are trying to solve editor and model problems in the renderer.

You can validate entered values in a custom `TableCellEditor`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513). You can handle *dependent* columns in the `TableModel`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513).

In a comment you say, "If I am not wrong, [`prepareRenderer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29) needs looping of all the rows, right?"

No, [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) "internal implementations always use this method to prepare renderers so that this default behavior can be safely overridden by a subclass." Overriding `prepareRenderer()` is most useful when changes must be be selectively applied to *all* renderers.

See [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details.