# How to change Background Color in definite table cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have CustomTableCellRender

```
  
public class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer defaultCellRenderer;

    public CustomCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer defaultCellRenderer) {
        this.defaultCellRenderer = defaultCellRenderer;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object ovalue, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        String val = (String) ovalue;
        Component c = defaultCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, ovalue, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (c != null) {
            if (val.equals("0h")) {
                c.setForeground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }
            return c;
        } else return null;
    }
}
```

...

```
 

            TableCellRenderer renderer = new CustomCellRenderer(sumTable.getDefaultRenderer(columnModel.getColumn(i).getClass()));
            columnModel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

and it worked normal util I need change cell Background Color     it sets Color not in certain cells and in all column, all cells.

```
...
            if (val.equals("0h")) {
                c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }
...
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your else statement, you need to set your background back to something. E.g. :
`c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);`

Answer (score 3):

The reason is (as often) the infamous color memory of the DefaultTableCellRenderer, as [described in a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617446/203657)

The problem in your particular context is that you use the same instance of the renderer as delegate *and* as default renderer elsewhere. Easiest solution is to use 2 different instances (after all, you know which type of renderers are installed by default).

Most simple solution for custom coloring (or other visual decorations of cells), is to use [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) with its consistent configuration support for rendering components.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do?

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table, Object ovalue, boolean isSelected, 
    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
```

- has two parameters `int row` and `int column` use these two coordinates in the [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) matrix,
- have to accepting and don't forger that all(???) `Arrays in Java` started with `zero`
- `(0, 0)` is `first column` in the `first row`

EDIT

[one of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410839/highlights-substring-in-the-tablecells-which-is-using-for-jtable-filetering)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class HiglightNumberValueInTableCell {

    private String testS;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("frameTitle");
    private JScrollPane tblS = new JScrollPane();
    private JTable tbl;
    private Vector<String> rOrH;
    private long t1 = 0L;
    private long t2 = 0L;

    public HiglightNumberValueInTableCell() {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int regLenght = 25000;
        int chars = 0;
        AlphaChars aChars = new AlphaChars();
        testS = aChars.getNext(regLenght);
        rOrH = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Vector<String>> rowD = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (int e = 0; e < regLenght;) {
            chars++;
            //if (chars > 50) { //one char in table cell
            if (chars > 20) {
                chars = 1;
                rowD.add(rOrH);
                rOrH = new Vector<String>();
            }
            //String str = (testS.substring(e, (e + 1))).toString();//one char in table cell
            String str = (testS.substring(e, (e + 5))).toString();
            if (str != null) {
                rOrH.add(str);
            } else {
                rOrH.add("");
            }
            //e++;//one char in table cell
            e += 5;
        }
        rOrH = new Vector<String>();
        //for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {//one char in table cell
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            rOrH.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        }
        tbl = new JTable(rowD, rOrH);
        tblS = new JScrollPane(tbl, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        tblS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 403));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tblS, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.pack();
        addColumnRenderes();
    }

    private void addColumnRenderes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            RowColorRenderer rowRenderer = new RowColorRenderer(i);
            TableColumn column = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer(rowRenderer);
        }
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                showFrame();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private void showFrame() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
                t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("miliSec:" + (t2 - t1)); //aver. 45 miliSec.
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private class RowColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int colNo = 0;

        RowColorRenderer(int col) {
            colNo = col;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;
            if (!isSelected) {
                if (table.getValueAt(row, colNo) != null) {
                    String str = table.getValueAt(row, colNo).toString();
                    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                        if (Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(str).find()) {
                            if (((Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && (!(Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.magenta);
                                setBackground(Color.orange);
                            } else if ((!(Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && ((Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.blue);
                                setBackground(Color.yellow);
                            } else if (((Pattern.compile("[02468]").matcher(str).find()))
                                    && ((Pattern.compile("[13579]").matcher(str).find()))) {
                                setForeground(Color.red);
                                setBackground(Color.cyan);
                            }
                            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
                            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                        } else {
                            setBackground(table.getBackground());
                            setForeground(table.getForeground());
                            setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 8));
                            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    private class AlphaChars {

        public static final int MIN_LENGTH = 2000;
        private java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        private char[] AlphaChars = {
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
            'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q',
            'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '+', '-', '*', '/', '<', '>', '&',
            '#', '@', '{', '}', '?', ':', '_', '"', '!', ')', '('};

        public String getNext() {
            StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < MIN_LENGTH; i++) {
                strbuf.append(getAlphaChars()[getRand().nextInt(getAlphaChars().length)]);
            }
            return strbuf.toString();
        }

        public String getNext(int reqLenght) {
            StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < reqLenght; i++) {
                strbuf.append(getAlphaChars()[getRand().nextInt(getAlphaChars().length)]);
            }
            return strbuf.toString();
        }

        public java.util.Random getRand() {
            return rand;
        }

        public void setRand(java.util.Random aRand) {
            rand = aRand;
        }

        public char[] getAlphaChars() {
            return AlphaChars;
        }

        public void setAlphaChars(char[] aAlphaChars) {
            AlphaChars = aAlphaChars;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HiglightNumberValueInTableCell hnvit = new HiglightNumberValueInTableCell();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to change background color in cell, where was written "0h", but I get ALL cells with background color GRAY.
I remember, that arrays in java start with zero, but how this helps me?

Comment: Ok. I can use getTableCellRender, but what do I need to put in parametr Object?

Comment: [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: @trashgod that's not a good option in this context as it requires to subclass the table: hooking there is appropriate for some framework-style decoration (like f.i. done in SwingX) or effects that should be applied across all types of rendering components or for a complete row. For per-value decorations, doing so in a custom renderer is the way to go

Comment: @kleopatra I thing not true, this is advantage of prepareRenderer, that not causing effect described in your answer +1 (Robs answer to Jerome jduprez, I have only the code not url reference to OTN)

Comment: the color memory is the same, independ of where you decorate. Though, thinking about it, in this context it might be true: the reason for its appearance is that while using "elsewhere" it's not resetted. Anyway, biased me would always recommend to not re-invent the wheel, simply use SwingX rendering support and you'll never again have to worry about that crappy default implementation :-)

Comment: @kleopatra yes, agreed with SwingX and Gob bless you for this great job :-),