# List of result from searching JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Having read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) and not understood the concept, I had to post my issue here. I am trying take the input value from Keyword `JTextField` and filter my `JTable` `table_job`. 
[image]

When search button is pressed, it should change the table in `Job List` panel to only display the set of jobs which includes the keyword in any of the column in its table. Currently, I am having no luck and am getting blank screens.

Here is the Job List Screen

[image]

The table on right does not update according to keyword.

Here is what I tried and failed, I am new to table filtering.

```
try {              
    jobTableInit(); 
    String value = keyword.getText();

    TableRowSorter sorter;
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(new DefaultTableModel());
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> rowFilter = null;
    try {
       rowFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter(keyword.getText());
    }
    catch(java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException ex) {
       return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rowFilter);
    table_job.setRowSorter(sorter);
 }            
 catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }
```

Can somebody suggest recommendations or show me a simple example code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). And **use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.** The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: *"display jobs which include the matching term"*  See [How to use Tables - Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default there are two ways

1. use custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and search in the [XxxTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) (or `JTables` view by using `Pattern`), more about Comparator is described in `JTables tutorial` about [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)
2. use built_in [RowFilter in TableRowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), then filtered `JTables view` returns desired `List_of_Xxx`
3. [another idea is only to hightlighting matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410839/highlights-substring-in-the-tablecells-which-is-using-for-jtable-filetering)

Comment: there is possible to search from both JTextFields, apply RowFilter to concrete TableColumn,nnot whole JTable, only one column, I can't see any issue,