# how can i programatically select a particular text from JTable when i do search in it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

here are the screenshots of the application

[image: This is how it look like when we run it]

[image: I want to make it like this]

Rows will be displayed in the Table according to the text which is written in the search textfield.
Now i want to mark that particular text as per the shown in the second image with the yellow color
I know how to select a row or a particular cell.
but I don't know how to select a particular text inside the cell of any row in the table.

I am guessing you know how to search in JTable, so I am not pasting code of it here.

Comment: [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) !!

Answer (score 3):

You can look over the **SwingX** library. It has this kind of function as you said predefined it it. You just need to add it to your table. [This](http://swingx.java.net/) is where you can find it. Give it a try you will surely like it.

Comment: @Deepak Odedara yeah, SwingX _basically_ supports visual decorations (via Highlighter/-Predicate) - your particular requirement is provided by our [X/MatchingTextHighlighter](https://java.net/projects/swinglabs-demos/sources/svn/show/trunk/SwingXSet6/swingxdemos/src/org/jdesktop/swingx/demos/search?rev=1326) which never made it out off the demos :-) Working fine, probably has problems with RToL

Answer (score 3):

The basic premise would be to use a custom `TableCellRenderer` that provided the functionality that you require.

The problem is how to implement it.

I would create a `TableCellRenderer` based on a `JTextField`, remove it's border and make it transparent.  This will allow you to use the text highlighting functionality provided by `JTextCompoent` to highlight portions of the text, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13449000#13449000).

The next problem is then knowing what to highlight.  There are a number of possibilities.

You could provide a method in your table model that could return the current text that should be highlighted.

I'd, personally, probably use the `JTable#putClientProperty` and `JTable#getClientProperty` methods to seed the search text.

Or, you could actually provide a simple model that directly to the renderer which had a method that returned the current search text.  This might actually be more useful as you could link it to field, the method building the filter and the renderers and allow them to simply seed each other

Comment: see [here(easier)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16740520/714968) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410839/highlights-substring-in-the-tablecells-which-is-using-for-jtable-filetering),

Comment: @mKorbel I knew SwingX could do row/column highlighting wasn't sure if it could selective highlighting though

Comment: I'not talking about SwingX,  forgot about, just about Html and Regex, even (@kleopatra) is around

Comment: SwingX highlighters can do ... everything :-) They just need to be implemented, exact textMatching is not provided by default, but available - [see my comment to the other] answer(http://stackoverflow.com/a/17850598/203657)

Comment: @kleopatra you know very well that I love SwingX, I want to hightlighing simple and clear way by Rob and Html