# CellRenderer - Making text bold

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, custom-renderer

How to make the text in JTable bold, I tried the following, It does work for colours but for making the text bold i'm going wrong somewhere

```
    class ColourRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tblData,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                tblData, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (tblData.getValueAt(row, 3).equals("M")) {
            cellComponent.setForeground(forMen);

        } else {
            cellComponent.setForeground(forWomen);

        }
        return cellComponent;
    }

    class boldRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tblData,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    tblData, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if (tblData.getValueAt(row, 1).equals(bib)) {
                cellComponent.setFont(cellComponent.getFont().deriveFont(
                        Font.BOLD));
            } else {
                cellComponent.setFont(cellComponent.getFont().deriveFont(
                        Font.PLAIN));
            }

            return cellComponent;
        }
    }
}
```

and this in the class that with the table

```
tblData.getColumn("Bib no").setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
tblData.getColumn("M/F").setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create a bold font but do nothing with it: You never call `setFont(...)` anywhere.

i.e.,

```
if (tblData.getValueAt(row, 1).equals(bib)) {
   // you must call setFont(...) for a font to change
   cellComponent.setFont(cellComponent.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
} else {  
   // don't forget to set the font back if condition not true
   cellComponent.setFont(cellComponent.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
}

// changing foreground color:
if (tblData.getValueAt(row, 3).equals("M")) {
   cellComponent.setForeGround(MEN_COLOR); // a constant
} else {  
   cellComponent.setForeGround(myTable.getForeground());
}
```

---

For colors, set the foreground color to null in your else block to have your colors change back to default.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CustomRendererExample extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] COLUMNS = { "M/F", "Fubar" };
   public static final String[] FUBARS = { "Fubar", "Snafu" };
   public static final String[] M_F = { "M", "F" };
   protected static final Color M_COLOR = Color.red;
   private DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 5);
   private JTable table = new JTable(dm);

   public CustomRendererExample() {
      add(new JScrollPane(table));
      DefaultCellEditor mfEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(M_F));
      table.getColumn(COLUMNS[0]).setCellEditor(mfEditor);
      table.getColumn(COLUMNS[0]).setCellRenderer(
            new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
               @Override
               public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                     Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                     int row, int column) {
                  Component superRenderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
                        value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                  if (value != null && value.equals(M_F[0])) {
                     superRenderer.setForeground(M_COLOR);
                  } else {
                     superRenderer.setForeground(null);
                  }

                  return superRenderer;
               }
            });

      DefaultCellEditor fubarEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(
            FUBARS));
      table.getColumn(COLUMNS[1]).setCellEditor(fubarEditor);
      table.getColumn(COLUMNS[1]).setCellRenderer(
            new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
               @Override
               public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                     Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                     int row, int column) {
                  Component superRenderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
                        value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                  if (value != null && value.equals(FUBARS[0])) {
                     superRenderer.setFont(superRenderer.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                  } else {
                     superRenderer.setFont(superRenderer.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                  }

                  return superRenderer;
               }
            });

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CustomRendererExample mainPanel = new CustomRendererExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Renderer Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, how would i have to change it to have the colour change as well? because now its bold and coloured? tblData.getColumn("M/F").setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());

if (tblData.getValueAt(row, 3).equals("M")) {
    cellComponent.setForeground(forMen);

   }

Comment: @user3405919: we can't read code in comments. Edit your question with the new code added to the bottom if you still have a question. Also, you should be able how to set the foreground color here, no? You set the color to `null` in the else block.

Comment: i just tried what you gave, but maybe im doing something wrong but the table still goes with both changes, so changes the colour and makes it bold, edited the code

Comment: @user3405919 `cellComponent.setForeground(null);` should be `cellComponent.setForeground(myJTable.getForeground())`, test for value isn't proper too, and etc.. , [see this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6421385/714968)

Comment: @user3405919: You should use separate cell renderers for each separate column.

Comment: okay, but then i get "No enclosing instance of type Window3 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Window3 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Window3)."

as error

Comment: @user3405919: if you're still stuck, time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3405919: for example, my [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has been created and posted above.